# Django SQL query count

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have the following models in Django:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    published_date = models.DateField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

There are 9 records in the Author table and 4 in the Book table.

How many SQL queries would be issued when Book.objects.select_related().all() is evaluated?

My guess was 4, because there are 4 rows in the Book table, so 1 query each to search for all the authors related to each book. Why is my answer wrong?

The possible choices are 5, 4, 10 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[select_related(*fields)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Returns a `QuerySet` that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a **single more complex query** but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.